# Anyway to change the default CMS path for Sitecore e.g. /sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to change the default CMS path on Sitecore to some other alias? For example going from http://website.com/sitecore to http://website.com/somethingelse

Comment: Please check [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: May I ask what the reason for the change is? Your content authoring environment should **not** be a public facing web server. The CM should be inside the company firewall.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you should be able to do this by changing the virtualPath value of the shell and login (possibly more) sites in the configuration (default located in the web.config). 
Never tried it before though.

```
<site name="shell" virtualFolder="/somethingelse/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" disableBrowserCaching="true" />
```

Comment: I think the issue will be files physically located on disk on the CM instance especially, e.g. /sitecore/admin/Login.aspx and there are a lot of hard coded references to these as redirect in the Sitecore Kernel